# MemoryError: Unable to allocate 30.6 TiB for an array with shape (2049135, 2049135) and data type float64

Tags: python, time-series, arima

I am working with Time Series and during running the ARIMA model
it gives me a memory error below

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 30.6 TiB for an array with shape (2049135, 2049135) and data type float64
```

my parameters

```
# 1,1,2 ARIMA Model
model = ARIMA(data.Sub_metering_3, order=(1,1,2))
model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
print(model_fit.summary())
```

any idea how to solve it?

I have tried to remove paging still didn't work

I am running Windows 10 Anaconda

Comment: 30 terabytes is a *lot* of memory. Even if you could fit that much memory into your computer, its processor wouldn't be able to address it.

Comment: You need to process the data in batches

Comment: That really is a very large dataset. Can you please share some details on the data and how you are processing it? Looking at the shape of your data I think that there was a mistake during transposing.